# Ссылка на англоязычный сайт в диалоге закрытия вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, статус-запланировано, локализация, нет-в-transifex

В диалоге закрытия вопросов есть две ссылки на одну и ту же страницу, но первая из них — [на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), а вторая — [на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обе ссылки должны вести на страницу на русском языке.

Comment: *русский* царь, *английская* королева ;) а тут, вероятно, речь о *русскоязычном* и *англоязычном* сайте/ресурсе. Уж простите мне мою въедливость ))

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: Так вы исправьте )

Comment: @NickVolynkin у меня нет полномочий ;)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown даже предлагать правку нельзя?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, неа. Во всяком случае, я в мобильном аппе такой опции не вижу.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: подозреваю, что на Мете нельзя предлагать правки к авторским сообщениям (к общим можно). Авторские можно только править напрямую, после 1000 репутации http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @NickVolynkin, видно так и есть. Здесь ссылка 'правка' задиммлена (dimmed), а на SO есть, я проверил.